# Find year high and year low in mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with many records (major columns are Date, Company Names, Closing Price. What i want to achieve is to use php to display all unique company names in the first column, most recent price in the 2nd (using date), Highest Price of all unique companies in database in the 3rd column and lowest price of all unique companies in the database. Please, how can i achieve this?

```
$query      =   "SELECT date, company, MIN(close), MAX (Close) FROM pricelist   GROUP BY company";
$result     =   mysql_query($query);
$num_rows   =   mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
    $id         =   mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $date       =   mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $company    =   mysql_result($result,$i,"company");
    $close      =   mysql_result($result,$i,"close");
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#d7dde3\"><td align=right class=no_text>".$company."</td><td align=right class=norm_text>".number_format($close, 2, '.', ',')."&nbsp;</td><td align=right class=norm_text>".$date."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
```

Here is what i am trying to achieve:

```
 Company Name Year High Date       Year Low Date 
 Google       $20       02/17/2014 $10      05/13/2014 
 Apple        $40       01/22/2014 $34      04/05/2014
```

Comment: What happened to `date`? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Here is what i am trying to achieve

Company Name   Year High   Date         Year Low   Date
Google         $20         02/17/2014    $10        05/13/2014
Apple          $40         01/22/2014    $34        04/05/2014

Answer (score 0):

Select all records by date, then use php arrays, asort() - low->high, arsort() - high->low.

Find more about php array here: [PHP Array Sorting](http://www.php.net//manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, but not tested

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, price, MAX (price),MIN(price) FROM pricelist   
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. Further, it's use in conjunction with GROUP BY is redundant.